# Toggle the active state on both content tab and the nav tabs with bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Using jQuery, I am trying to toggle the `tab-pane`. For now It works only for the `tab-pane` but I also want to remove active class from the `data-toggle="tab"`.

```js
$('[data-toggle=tab]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active show')) {
    $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass('active show');
  }
});
```

```css
img {width: 48px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
      <h5></h5>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
      <h5></h5>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
      <h5></h5>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="container tab-pane"><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 case-tab-content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Imgur_icon.svg/240px-Imgur_icon.svg.png">
        <h4>Sometext</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Found a solution which is worked for now. But still I am looking for  compact code to understand me better. Please see the below code that I am using for now.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kaustav790/pen/rogBqK ----- Added the pen here